# Should I still shake the lights?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

In Luigi's Mansion a trick to get a bit of extra money was to shake every light; hanging lights could often be spun around, then releasing a bunch of cash after being spun enough.

Lights don't seem to spin at all in Dark Moon, and vacuuming them has yielded no treasure so far. Are lights no longer treasure-keepers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**. I've not beat the game as of you yet but I do know in the first room, on the first mission, if you vacuum off all the lights monies will rain down upon you.

Basically, anything in this game you can interact with has the chance of giving you something. Vacuum, dark light, strobe, everything. The ceiling fans also often lead to treasure if you spin them for long enough, but not always. But this is true of almost every object in the game.

Even though you're in the same mansion throughout multiple missions the same stuff will react differently almost every time. There are even some events that can only be triggered on specific missions.